# Is there official documentation for official documentation and getting help system of Mathematica?

Tags: documentation

Mathematica has very high quality and extensive documentation and good getting help system (`? Solve` as an example; there maybe are more too). Is there all including official documentation about Mathematica official documentation (describing documentation structure and its effective use) and help system use (tips, tricks, different ways of use)?

Some people may think this is an not specific and because of it it is offtopic question. But I have two very specific questions:

1. Such good and extensive documentation as Mathematica has should have its documentation describing its structure and effective use. Where it is?
2. Help system should have its documentations. Where it is?

Answer (score 12):

The "How to" page [Get Help in the Wolfram System](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetHelpInTheWolframSystem.html) is a good start.  The links on that page lead to in-depth articles (with videos) about both interactive and programmatic ways to learn about Wolfram Language features.

[image]

Comment: How can one find this page without using the precise title `howto/GetHelpInTheWolframSystem`? Searching _Get Help in the Wolfram System_ in the document doesn't seem to help…

Comment: @xzczd It is pretty hard to find in recent versions without resorting to a trial-and-error search.  In earlier versions, the documentation center used to have a prominent link to the ["How to" Topics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebooksAndDocumentsHowToTopicsOverview.html) page.  There are many hidden gems to be found in the directory `{$InstallationDirectory,"Documentation",$Language,"System"} // FileNameJoin // SystemOpen`.